# Getting errno after a write operation

Tags: linux, go

I have the following Go code which will eventually fill the disk and fail with `ENOSPC` (just a proof of concept). How can I determine from the `err` returned by `os.Write` that it indeed failed because of `ENOSPC` (so I need a way to grab `errno` after the write operation) ?

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fd, _ := os.Create("dump.txt")

    defer fd.Close()

    for {
        buf := make([]byte, 1024)

        _, err := fd.Write(buf)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("%T %v", err, err)
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Updated the program as @FUZxxl suggested:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    fd, _ := os.Create("dump.txt")

    defer fd.Close()

    for {
        buf := make([]byte, 1024)

        _, err := fd.Write(buf)
        if err != nil {

            log.Printf("%T %v\n", err, err)
            errno, ok := err.(syscall.Errno)

            if ok {
                log.Println("type assert ok")
                if errno == syscall.ENOSPC {
                    log.Println("got ENOSPC")
                }
            } else {
                log.Println("type assert not ok")
            }
            break
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm not getting the expected result. Here is the output:

```
2015/02/15 10:13:27 *os.PathError write dump.txt: no space left on device
2015/02/15 10:13:27 type assert not ok
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File operations generally return an [`*os.PathError`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#PathError); cast `err` to `os.PathError` and use the `Err` field to examine the underlying cause, like this:

```
patherr, ok := err.(*os.PathError)
if ok && patherr.Err == syscall.ENOSPC {
    log.Println("Out of disk space!")
}
```

Comment: I actually thought this would work, but it seems `err` can't be converted to `syscall.Errno` :(  See my updated question.

Comment: @Unknown That's strange. Can you tell me what `fmt.Printf("%T", err)`  says? What platform are you on?

Comment: You can see it in the output above, `err` is an `*os.PathError`. I'm on Linux amd64.

Comment: It works, but please fully update your example before I accept your answer (i.e. convert err to `os.PathError` and use `errno.Err`) so that it's correct if anyone else needs this.